# Failed on Injecting Akka Actor to Play Framework 2.5 with Guice

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, akka, playframework-2.5

I am trying to use an Akka actor in my Play 2.5 application with dependency injection. I basically followed [the documentation on that](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka), and here's a glimpse of my code:

### The Actor

Basically, I have a simple actor that receive some data, process it, and send it back to the caller.

```
package actors    

import akka.actor._
import akka.pattern.{AskTimeoutException, ask}
import akka.util.Timeout
import javax.inject._

import com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted
import play.api.Configuration

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.Future

object ServiceActor {
  val ConfigKey = "actors.path" // remote actor path

  trait Factory {
    def apply(key: String): Actor
  }
}

class ServiceActor @Inject()(configuration: Configuration,
                                   actorSystem: ActorSystem,
                                   @Assisted key: String)
                                  (implicit val ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends Actor {
  import ServiceActor._

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.minutes)

  def receive = {
    case data: SomeData => sender ! someFunction(data)
  }

  // implemented in the real code, omitted because not important for the question
  def someFunction = ??? 
}
```

### The Module

As per documentation, I need to make a simple module, and activate it. Here's the module:

```
package modules

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport

import actors.ServiceActor

class ServiceModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure = {
    bindActor[ServiceActor]("service-actor")
  }
}
```

And then I activate this module by adding the following line to `application.conf`:

```
play.modules {
  enabled += modules.ServiceModule
}
```

### The Controller

Finally, I try to use the actor in a controller:

```
package controllers

import akka.actor._
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import javax.inject._

import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

@Singleton
class SearchController @Inject()(@Named("service-actor") serviceActor: ActorRef)
                                (implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends Controller {

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.minutes)

  def search(param: String) = Action.async {

    val request = SomeRequestType(param)

    (serviceActor ? request).mapTo[SomeResponseType] map { result =>
      Ok(result.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I can understand, I have followed the documentation perfectly, but calling the controller give me this error:

```
[AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://application/user/service-actor#-366470383]] 
had already been terminated. 
Sender[null] sent the message of type "some.namespace.SomeRequestType".]
```

As far as I can understand, the error is about how the actor is a `null`, and we can't send message to it. While the error code said "had already been terminated", it looks like the actor's never been initiated in the first place.

I'm not sure where to look first, and what am I doing wrong as I have no experience in using Guice.

The question is, what am I doing wrong? Why didn't the actor initiated, or if it is indeed already terminated, why is it terminated? How do I fix this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your use case simple enough to eliminate Guice and just use javax.inject?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have already solved the issue. However I am still posting answers here just for some new comers' reference since it took me a while to figure out the cause of this issue.

> **As far as I can understand, the error is about how the actor is a null, and we can't send message to it.**

Not exactly. Ask pattern ? has an implicit parameter of sender, which defaults to be ActorRef.noSender, the source code is [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/bd71487646b3846d7bbc6deafae7a6bbce6a15c5/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/AskSupport.scala#L277).

Normally, if you're inside an Actor you have an implicit ActorRef in scope called self, but since you're not in an Actor it's just taking the default.

> **While the error code said "had already been terminated", it looks like the actor's never been initiated in the first place.**

Correct. Most likely your actor was never initiated correctly in the first place. In your console, you should see more error messages than what you are seeing from the response of Play Webpage.

For example below is the error I actually got before I got the AskTimeoutException.

```
1 error
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: akka://application/user/user-actor: exception during creation
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:193)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:608)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:484)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
Caused by: com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
```

To wrap up, you may want to check the sbt console again and also your injection to make sure the actor was initiated in the first place.